# How can I prevent my grease pencil objects from overlapping light trails?

Tags: geometry-nodes, eevee-render-engine, lighting, grease-pencil

I'm using the [Light Trails Addon](https://blendermarket.com/products/light-trails-generator) by Specoolar in my scene but the grease pencil objects within the scene are always in front of the light trail. The trail is in front of the grease pencil object in 3D space and Z pass is on.

[image: Grease pencil objects overlapping light trail]

Comment: Would using a separate render pass work?
Chuck the trail onto it's own view layer, render and composite it on top.

Comment: Check for the (sometimes automatically assigned.. eg for Line Art) ''In Front" setting in GP > Object tab > Viewport Display panel? Nice scene,BTW :)